# Why is my ANTLR4 parser grammar erroring 'no viable alternative at input'?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

When I run my grammar (lexer and parser) in powershell, it produces these errors:

```
line 1:6 no viable alternative at input 'global '
```

I've tried searching google and SO about the errors and the infinite loop, but I can't really understand anything (probably because I just started antlr a few days ago).

Test file:

```
global a = 2
```

Lexer grammar:

```
lexer grammar Test;
// tokens { SMT, SST, SCH, USM, USS, USC, NMT, NST, NCH, UNM, UNS, NAS, UNC, NAC, MLC, SLC, PXI, DXI, PXF, DXF, PXB, DXB, PXD, DXD, PXP, DXP, PRX, DEX, IMG, FLT, DBL, DCM, PRC, INT, CKW, KWR, RMH, IMH, NAN, IND, UND, NIL, NON, TRU, FLS, IDN, WSP, BKS, SMC, CMA, IVC }
MST: '\'\'' -> pushMode(multiline);
SMT: SPS SDSQ ODQ*? SDSQ;
SST: SPS '"' NTD* '"';
SCH: [rf] SLSQ OQC SLSQ;
USM: SPS SDSQ ODQ*? EOF;
USS: SPS '"' NTD* (EOL* ODC*)? EOF;
USC: [rf] SLSQ OQC? EOF;
NMT: SDSQ ODQ*? SDSQ;
NST: '"' NTD* '"';
NCH: SLSQ OQC SLSQ;
UNM: SDSQ ODQ*? EOF;
UNS: '"' NTD* (EOL* ODC*)? EOF;
NAS: SPS? '"' NTD* EOL* ODC* '"';
UNC: SLSQ OQC? EOF;
NAC: (('p'[f]?|[f]?'p')? SLSQ OQC+ SLSQ? | [rpf]? SLSQ OQC OQC+ SLSQ?);
MLC: '##' NDH* '##'? -> skip;
SLC: '--' NEN* -> skip;
EOL: '\r'? '\n' | [\n\u000b\f\r\u0085\u2028\u2029];
EML: '[]';
EMS: '{}';
PXI: NUM 'E' NUM 'i';
DXI: NUM 'e' NUM 'i';
PXF: NUM 'E' NUM 'f';
DXF: NUM 'e' NUM 'f';
PXB: NUM 'E' NUM 'd';
DXB: NUM 'e' NUM 'd';
PXD: NUM 'E' NUM 'D';
DXD: NUM 'e' NUM 'D';
PXP: NUM 'E' NUM 'p'
| '+'? NUM 'E' NUM
;
DXP: NUM 'e' NUM 'p'
| '+'? NUM 'e' NUM
;
PRX: '-'? NUM 'E' NUM;
DEX: '-'? NUM 'e' NUM;
IMG: NUM? 'i';
FLT: NUM 'f'
| DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT DIGITFQ DIGITTQ
;
DBL: NUM 'd'
| DIGIT+ '.' DIGITE DIGITFQ DIGITGQ
;
DCM: NUM 'D'
| DIGIT+ '.' DIGITE DIGITE DIGITEQ DIGITFQ DIGITGQ
;
PRC: NUM 'p'
| DIGIT+ '.' DIGITE DIGITE DIGITE DIGITE DIGIT*
; 
INT: INTEGER | DIGIT;
OPN: 'opn';
OUT: 'out';
OUTF: 'outf';
PRINT: 'print';
PRINTF: 'printf';
LAMBDA: 'lambda';
FUNC: 'func';
ERR: 'err';
ERRF: 'errf';
ASSERT: 'assert';
ASSERTF: 'assertf';
FORMAT: 'format';
SWITCH: 'switch';
ABS: 'abs';
ASCII: 'ascii';
CALLABLE: 'callable';
CHR: 'chr';
DIR: 'dir';
EVAL: 'eval';
EXEC: 'exec';
FILTER: 'filter';
GET: 'get';
HASH: 'hash';
ID: 'id';
INST: 'inst';
SUB: 'sub';
SUPER: 'super';
MAX: 'max';
MIN: 'min';
OBJ: 'obj';
ORD: 'ord';
POWF: 'pow';
REV: 'rev';
REPR: 'repr';
ROUND: 'round';
FLOOR: 'floor';
CEIL: 'ceil';
MUL: 'mul';
SORT: 'sort';
ADD: 'add';
ZIP: 'zip';
WAIT: 'wait';
SECS: 'secs';
MILS: 'mils';
BENCHMARK: 'benchmark';
HAS: 'has';
SIBLING: 'sibling';
A: 'a';
CHILD: 'child';
OF: 'of';
WHILE: 'while';
FOR: 'for';
DO: 'do';
DEL: 'del';
NEW: 'new';
IMPORT: 'import';
EXPORT: 'export';
DEF: 'def';
END: 'end';
GLOBAL: 'global';
BREAK: 'break';
CONTINUE: 'continue';
NOT: 'not';
AND: 'and';
OR: 'or';
IN: 'in';
CASE: 'case';
DEFAULT: 'default';
RETURN: 'return';
TRY: 'try';
EXCEPT: 'except';
FINALLY: 'finally';
ELIF: 'elif';
IF: 'if';
ELSE: 'else';
AS: 'as';
STRT: 'str';
INTT: 'int';
NUMT: 'num';
DECIMALT: 'decimal';
FLOATT: 'float';
DOUBLET: 'double';
PRECISET: 'precise';
EXPNT: 'expn';
CONST: 'const';
REPEAT: 'repeat';
UNTIL: 'until';
THEN: 'then';
CHART: 'char';
GOTO: 'goto';
LABEL: 'label';
TYPET: 'type';
USING: 'using';
BOOLT: 'bool';
PUBLIC: 'public';
PROTECTED: 'protected';
PRIVATE: 'private';
CLASSD: 'class';
SELF: 'self';
STRUCTD: 'struct';
FROM: 'from';
XOR: 'xor';
LISTD: 'list';
TUPLED: 'tuple';
DICTD: 'dict';
SETD: 'set';
IMAGT: 'imag';
REALT: 'real';
WHERE: 'where';
PASS: 'pass';
G_G: '_G';
L_L: '_L';
HEXT: 'hex';
BINT: 'bin';
OCTT: 'oct';
MAP: 'map';
ANYT: 'any';
VOIDT: 'void';
IS: 'is';
A_FDV: '//=';
A_CDV: '*/=';
A_NOR: '||=';
A_FAC: '=!=';
A_LTE: '=<=';
A_GTE: '=>=';
A_EQL: '===';
A_NEQ: '!==';
A_CON: '..=';
A_NXR: '$$=';
A_BRS: '>>=';
A_NND: '&&=';
A_BLS: '<<=';
A_DCL: '::=';
A_CLD: ':.=';
A_KUN: '=**';
A_VUN: '=*';
A_DOT: '.=';
A_POW: '^=';
A_NOT: '=!';
A_BNT: '=~';
A_LEN: '=#';
A_PER: '=%';
A_MUL: '*=';
A_DIV: '/=';
A_MOD: '%=';
A_ADD: '+=';
A_SUB: '-=';
A_LET: '=<';
A_GRT: '=>';
A_BND: '&=';
A_BXR: '$=';
A_BOR: '|=';
A_TND: '?=';
A_TOR: ':=';
A_NML: '=';
NND: '&&';
NXR: '$$';
NOR: '||';
CLP: '()';
SUP: '::';
SIB: ':.';
KUN: '**';
INC: '++';
DEC: '+-';
FDV: '//';
CDV: '*/';
CON: '..';
BLS: '<<';
BRS: '>>';
LTE: '<=';
GTE: '>=';
EQL: '==';
NEQ: '!=';
LPR: '(';
RPR: ')';
LBR: '[';
RBR: ']';
LBC: '{';
RBC: '}';
STR: '*';
POW: '^';
PLS: '+';
MNS: '-';
BNT: '~';
EXC: '!';
LEN: '#';
PER: '%';
DIV: '/';
LET: '<';
GRT: '>';
BND: '&';
BXR: '$';
BOR: '|';
TND: '?';
TOR: ':';
DOT: '.';
RMH: 'inf';
IMH: 'inf*i';
NAN: 'nan';
IND: 'ind';
UND: 'und';
NIL: 'nil'
| 'null';
NON: 'none';
TRU: 'true';
FLS: 'false';
IDN: AUL WORD*;
WSP: (('\r'? '\n') | [\u0009\u0020\u00a0\u1680\u2000-\u200a\u202f\u205f\u3000\n\u000b\f\r\u0085\u2028\u2029])+;
BKS: [\u007f\u0008]+;
SMC: ';';
CMA: ',';
SPC: ' ';
IVC: .;
mode multiline;
    SCE: ESCAPE -> type(SCN);
    SND: (SDSQ | EOF) -> popMode;
    SCN: '\'' ~'\'' | ~'\'';

mode multicom;
    CCE: '\\##' -> type(CCN);
    CND: ('##' | EOF) -> popMode;
    CCN: '#' ~'#' | ~'#';

fragment DIGITE: DIGITF DIGITF;
fragment DIGITEQ: DIGITFQ DIGITFQ;
fragment DIGITF: DIGITG DIGIT;
fragment DIGITFQ: DIGITGQ DIGITQ;
fragment SPS: 'pf' | 'fp' | [rpf];
fragment OCH: ESCAPE | ALL;
fragment OQC: ESCAPE | ~['];
fragment ODQ: ESCAPE | SCN;
fragment ODC: ESCAPE | ~["];
fragment NDN: ESCAPE | NED;
fragment AUL: [a-zA-Z_];
fragment DIGIT: [0-9];
fragment DECM: INTEGER '.' INTEGER;
fragment WORD: AUL | DIGIT;
fragment DIGITQ: DIGIT?;
fragment DIGITG: DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT;
fragment DIGITGQ: DIGIT? DIGIT? DIGIT?;
fragment DIGITT: DIGIT DIGIT;
fragment DIGITTQ: DIGIT? DIGIT?;
fragment INTEGER: DIGITG ('_'? DIGITG)* | DIGIT+;
fragment ALL: .;
fragment TNQ: '\\' SLSQ | ~['];
fragment TNDQQ: '\\"' | ~["];
fragment NDH: CCN;
fragment NEN: ~[\n\u000b\f\r\u0085\u2028\u2029];
fragment NED: ~[\n\u000b\f\r\u0085\u2028\u2029"];
fragment ENN: ESCAPE | NEN;
fragment NTD: ESCAPE | NED;
fragment HEX: DIGIT | [a-fA-F];
fragment HEXQ: HEX?;
fragment SPCF: ' ';
fragment ESCAPE: '\\' ( 'x' HEX HEXQ | 'u' HEX HEXQ HEXQ HEXQ | 'U' HEX HEXQ HEXQ HEXQ HEXQ HEXQ HEXQ HEXQ | 'X' HEX HEXQ HEXQ HEXQ HEXQ HEXQ HEXQ HEXQ HEXQ HEXQ HEXQ HEXQ HEXQ HEXQ HEXQ HEXQ| 'o' OCT OCTQ OCTQ | 'O' OCT OCTQ OCTQ OCTQ OCTQ OCTQ | ESCS );
fragment ESCS: ['"nrtbfv\\];
fragment OCT: [0-7];
fragment OCTQ: OCT?;
fragment NUM: DECM | INTEGER;
fragment SLDQ: ["];
fragment SLSQ: ['];
fragment SDSQ: SLSQ SLSQ;
```

Parser grammar:

```
parser grammar TestP;
options { tokenVocab=Test; }
program: line (EOL line*) EOL? EOF;
line: expression+ SMC* | expression* SMC+;
expression: wsp* assign_expression wsp*;
assign_expression: <assoc=right> GLOBAL var_list wsp* aop wsp* (var_list wsp* aop wsp*)* or_expression (wsp* CMA wsp* or_expression)*;
or_expression: xor_expression (wsp* (NOR | OR) wsp* xor_expression)*;
xor_expression: and_expression (wsp* (NXR | XOR) wsp* and_expression)*;
and_expression: ternary (wsp* (NND | AND) wsp* ternary)*;
ternary: <assoc=right> bit_or (wsp* (AND | TND) wsp* bit_or wsp* (OR | TOR) wsp* bit_or)?;
bit_or: bit_xor (wsp* BOR wsp* bit_xor)*;
bit_xor: bit_and (wsp* BXR wsp* bit_and)*;
bit_and: eql_expr (wsp* BND wsp* eql_expr)*;
eql_expr: com_expr (wsp* (EQL | IS | NEQ | IS wsp* NOT) wsp* com_expr)*;
com_expr: shift_expr (wsp* (LET | LTE | GRT | GTE) wsp* shift_expr)*;
shift_expr: con_expr (wsp* (BLS | BRS) wsp* con_expr)*;
con_expr: one_expr (wsp* CON wsp* one_expr)*;
one_expr: perc_expr (wsp* (PLS | MNS) wsp* perc_expr)*;
perc_expr: fac_expr ((wsp* (STR | DIV | PER | FDV | CDV) wsp* fac_expr)+ | PER)*;
fac_expr: unary_expr EXC?;
unary_expr: (PLS | MNS | BNT | EXC | LEN | NOT)* crement_expr;
crement_expr: pow_expr (wsp* (INC|DEC) wsp* pow_expr | INC | DEC)*;
pow_expr: <assoc=right> unpack_expr (wsp* POW wsp* unpack_expr)*;
unpack_expr: (STR | KUN)* brackets_expr;
brackets_expr
    : tupled
    | LPR access_expr RPR
    | dictd
    | setd
    | LBC access_expr RBC
    | listd
    | LBR access_expr RBR
    | access_expr
;
var_list: assign ( wsp* CMA wsp* assign)*;
assign
    : idn
    | index
;
access_expr
    : atom ((DOT | SUP | SIB) atom)*
;
atom
    : litidn
    |datat
    | val
    | num
    | index
;
literal
    : strt
    | num
;
datat
    : listd
    | dictd
    | setd
    | tupled
;
listd
    : LBR wsp* comma_separated wsp* RBR
    | EML
;
dictd
    : LBC wsp* kvpair wsp*
    (
        CMA
        wsp*
        kvpair
        wsp*
    )+
    RBC
    | LBC wsp* kvpair wsp* RBC
;
setd
    : LBC wsp* comma_separated wsp* RBC
    | EMS
;
tupled: LPR wsp* comma_separated wsp* RPR;
comma_separated
    : expression
    (
        wsp*
        CMA
        wsp*
        expression
    )*
;
kvpair: expression wsp* TOR SPC wsp* expression;
litidn
    : literal
    | idn
;
typecast: typet LPR expression RPR;
call:
    (
        dictd
        | idn
        | index
    )
    (
        CLP
    |
        tupled
    )
;
strt
    : multi_line
    | single_line
    | char_string
;
idn
    : IDN
    | A
;
index: (datat | strt) LBR expression RBR;
multi_line
    : SMT
    | USM
    | NMT
    | UNM
;
single_line
    : SST
    | USS
    | NST
    | UNS
    | NAS
;
char_string
    : SCH
    | USC
    | NCH
    | UNC
    | NAC
;
num
    : exponential
    | non_exponential
;
exponential
    : PXI
    | DXI
    | PXF
    | DXF
    | PXB
    | DXB
    | PXD
    | DXD
    | PXP
    | DXP
    | PRX
    | DEX
;
non_exponential
    : IMG
    | FLT
    | DBL
    | DCM
    | PRC
    | INT
;
typet
    : STRT
    | INTT
    | NUMT
    | DECIMALT
    | FLOATT
    | DOUBLET
    | PRECISET
    | EXPNT
    | CHART
    | IMAGT
    | REALT
    | HEXT
    | BINT
    | OCTT
    | LISTD
    | SETD
    | DICTD
    | TUPLED
    | TYPET
    | BOOLT
;
wsp
    : WSP
    | EOL
;
bks_or_wsp
    : wsp
    | BKS
    | SPC
;
emd
    : EML
    | EMS
;
sep
    : SMC
    | CMA
    | TOR
;
/*
kwr
    : WHILE
    | FOR
    | DO
    | DEL
    | NEW
    | IMPORT
    | EXPORT
    | DEF
    | END
    | GLOBAL
    | BREAK
    | CONTINUE
    | NOT
    | AND
    | OR
    | IN
    | CASE
    | DEFAULT
    | RETURN
    | TRY
    | EXCEPT
    | FINALLY
    | ELIF
    | IF
    | ELSE
    | AS
    | CONST
    | REPEAT
    | UNTIL
    | THEN
    | GOTO
    | LABEL
    | USING
    | PUBLIC
    | PROTECTED
    | PRIVATE
    | SELF
    | FROM
    | XOR
    | IMAGT
    | REALT
    | WHERE
    | PASS
    | G_G
    | L_L
    | MAP
    | IS
;
ckw
    : OPN
    | OUT
    | OUTF
    | PRINT
    | PRINTF
    | LAMBDA
    | FUNC
    | ERR
    | ERRF
    | ASSERT
    | ASSERTF
    | FORMAT
    | SWITCH
    | ABS
    | ASCII
    | CALLABLE
    | CHR
    | DIR
    | EVAL
    | EXEC
    | FILTER
    | GET
    | HASH
    | ID
    | INST
    | SUB
    | SUPER
    | MAX
    | MIN
    | OBJ
    | ORD
    | POWF
    | REV
    | REPR
    | ROUND
    | FLOOR
    | CEIL
    | MUL
    | SORT
    | ADD
    | ZIP
    | WAIT
    | SECS
    | MILS
    | BENCHMARK
;
*/
val
    : RMH // 'inf'
    | IMH // 'inf*i'
    | NAN // 'nan'
    | IND // 'ind'
    | UND // 'und'
    | NIL // 'nil'
    | NON // 'none'
    | TRU // 'true'
    | FLS // 'false'
;
aop
    : A_FDV // '//='
    | A_CDV // '*/='
    | A_NOR // '||='
    | A_FAC // '=!='
    | A_LTE // '=<='
    | A_GTE // '=>='
    | A_EQL // '==='
    | A_NEQ // '!=='
    | A_CON // '..='
    | A_NXR // '$$='
    | A_BRS // '>>='
    | A_NND // '&&='
    | A_BLS // '<<='
    | A_DCL // '::='
    | A_CLD // ':.='
    | A_KUN // '=**'
    | A_VUN // '=*'
    | A_DOT // '.='
    | A_POW // '^='
    | A_NOT // '=!'
    | A_BNT // '=~'
    | A_LEN // '=#'
    | A_PER // '=%'
    | A_MUL // '*='
    | A_DIV // '/='
    | A_MOD // '%='
    | A_ADD // '+='
    | A_SUB // '-='
    | A_LET // '=<'
    | A_GRT // '=>'
    | A_BND // '&='
    | A_BXR // '$='
    | A_BOR // '|='
    | A_TND // '?='
    | A_TOR // ':='
    | A_NML // '='
;
opr
    : NND // '&&'
    | NXR // '$$'
    | NOR // '||'
    | CLP // '()'
    | SUP // '::'
    | SIB // ':.'
    | KUN // '**'
    | INC // '++'
    | DEC // '+-'
    | FDV // '//'
    | CDV // '*/'
    | CON // '..'
    | BLS // '<<'
    | BRS // '>>'
    | LTE // '<='
    | GTE // '>='
    | EQL // '=='
    | NEQ // '!='
    | LPR // '('
    | RPR // ')'
    | LBR // '['
    | RBR // ']'
    | LBC // '{'
    | RBC // '}'
    | STR // '*'
    | POW // '^'
    | PLS // '+'
    | MNS // '-'
    | BNT // '~'
    | EXC // '!'
    | LEN // '#'
    | PER // '%'
    | DIV // '/'
    | LET // '<'
    | GRT // '>'
    | BND // '&'
    | BXR // '$'
    | BOR // '|'
    | TND // '?'
    | TOR // ':'
    | DOT // '.'
;
/*
inl
    : strt
    | num
    | ckw
    | kwr
    | val
    | idn
    | bks_or_wsp
    | sep
    | emd
    | aop
    | opr
    | typet
    | IVC
;
*/
```

EDIT: Changed parser grammar, changed errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot of "Stuff" in this Lexer/Parser.  That's not a bad thing for a completed grammar, but I'd suggest that you "start small".  (There are a lot of "red flags" that you're not really "getting" ANTLR and how it works.)

An example:  Your `kwr` parserRule **appears** to list the keywords from your grammar.  It's quite unlikely that there's any place where you need to match "any keyword"

@momolechart is right that you don't have a path from your `program` rule to any rule that utilizes the `GLOBAL` tokens.

Let's start small, for just what you need for this expression:

You have:

- a `GLOBAL` keyword (token),
- an `A` token (?? this looks suspiciously like it should be an identifier, but, I'll take at face value, that 'a' has a particular meaning in your context
  since you defined a token rule for it.
- an `A_NML` token (value '=') (this just gets stranger and stranger, but I'll go with it)
- an `INT` token ('2')
- Oh, and several `WSP` tokens (I'll address how whitespace is normally handled)

Let's strip the Lexer down to handle that:

```
lexer grammar Test;
GLOBAL: 'global';
A: 'a';
INT: INTEGER;
A_NML: '=';
SMC: ';';
EOL: '\r'? '\n' | [\n\u000b\f\r\u0085\u2028\u2029];
WSP: (('\r'? '\n') | [\u0009\u0020\u00a0\u1680\u2000-\u200a\u202f\u205f\u3000\n\u000b\f\r\u0085\u2028\u2029])+ -> skip;
fragment DIGIT: [0-9];
fragment DIGITG: DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT;
fragment INTEGER: DIGITG ('_'? DIGITG)* | DIGIT+;
```

(I've tried to keep as much of your original Lexer grammar as possible.  I did take the liberty of handling whitespace the "normal way, i.e. using `-> skip`.  In your parser rules, I see a LOT of `wsp*`s (this removes that need)

Now we need to recognize the assignment statement. So, a minimal Parser grammar to handle that would be:

```
parser grammar TestP;
options { tokenVocab=Test; }
program: line (EOL line*) EOL? EOF;
line: expression+ SMC* | expression* SMC+;
expression:  assign_expression ;
assign_expression: GLOBAL A A_NML INT;
```

That was a *substantial* simplification of your `assign_expression`, but now you're "in business"; you're recognizing your sample input.  You can start building your grammar out from there.

Your immediate problem (as noted in the other answer) was that no rule referenced (directly, or indirectly) from `expression` recognized a `GLOBAL` keyword.

Now for longer term advice.  These grammars (to me) look like an attempt to do a literal translation of some technical spec (I can't imagine what the language is), into your best guess of how to represent that in ANTLR.

That is often quite ill-advised.  I'd suggest backing up a bit and learning ANTLR on some simpler efforts, and, once you have a grasp of ANTLR, then work on tackling this.  I'd also advise, if you're going to tackle anything this complex, getting and reading [*The Definitive ANTLR4 Reference*](https://pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr2/the-definitive-antlr-4-reference/) from pragmatic programmers.  It will be well worth your time.  (It actually calls out this approach to implementing tech specs into ANTLR as not such a good approach.)

Comment: Thank you, it helped me solve the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Both `global` and `a` are listed in your grammer under `kwr` rule.

`kwr` is mentioned in the `inl` rule which isn't used anywhere. So your parser don't know how to deal with `inl` and don't know what to do with two `inl` chained together (`global a`)

Comment: It still produces the same errors and still goes into an infinite loop after i removed `inl`.

Comment: EDIT: It produces different errors after I removed `a` in `kwr`.

Comment: @uknonot, remember that making a parser is basically making a tree with a top rule as a root. Here you have a branch `inl` which isn't connected to the tree as there is no way to go from your root rule to `inl`. You need to connect it somewhere.

Comment: @uknonot EDIT: didn't see that you have removed `inl` this doesn't change the problem as their is still no way in your grammar to go from the root rule to the `kwr` rule. The parser get the pattern expressed in the rule `kwr` but don't know what to do with it as it isn't mentioned anywhere. Remember that appart from the root rule, every other rule should be imbriqued in another one.

Comment: EDIT: removed probably all unused parser rules.

Comment: @uknonot Those rules probably shouldn't be unused. Your problem is about how to use them. By removing those rules, you just push the problem down the road. Now you have a token `GLOBAL` in your lexer. This token is not used by any rule in the parser so antlr still don't know what to do with it. Instead of removing rules, you should find how to insert them in your grammar.